# get image width and height then in cm by JS

Tags: javascript, image, size

how can I get an image's width and height in cm by JavaScript?
I wrote a simple script, but when images have different resolutions so it couldn't show correct w and h.
Please help me.
(sorry for my English)

Comment: How about adding your code example so that people can suggest improvements ?

Comment: In short: you can’t get the real dimension because images are built in pixels and different devices have a different pixel per inch ratio.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').width();
$('img').height();
```

or

```
$('img').clientWidth;
$('img').clientHeight;
```

Comment: I want width and height in cm!

Answer (score 0):

Small sample on pure JavaScript with pixel to cm converter (size depends on screen's DPI):

```js
var
  getSizeInCM,
  ready;

/* Convert px to cm */
getSizeInCM = function(sizeInPX) {
  
   return sizeInPX * 2.54 / (96 * window.devicePixelRatio)
};

ready = function() {
  
  var 
    img = document.getElementById('img'),
    width = getSizeInCM(img.clientWidth),
    height = getSizeInCM(img.clientHeight);

  alert('width: ' + width.toFixed(2) + ' cm, height: ' + height.toFixed(2) + ' cm');
};
```

```html
<body onload="ready()">
  <img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
</body>
```

Result (MacBook Pro late 2011, Google Chrome):

[image]

Result (Apple Iphone 6, Safari):

[image]

Comment: I want width and height in cm!

Answer (score 0):

If it is sufficient to assume 96 pixels per inch, the formula is to calculate `cm` is:

`centimeters = pixels * 2.54 / 96`

```js
function getImgSize() {
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var width = img.clientWidth * 2.54 / 96;
  var height = img.clientHeight * 2.54 / 96;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'width: ' + width + ', height: ' + height;
};
```

```html
<body onload="getImgSize()">
  <img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! but my program is dynamic and users have many images in different dpi!

Answer (score 0):

Some experiments with HTML5, to see which values actually get returned.

First of all I used a program called Dash to get an overview of the image API. It states that 'height' and 'width' are the rendered height/width of the image and that 'naturalHeight' and 'naturalWidth' are the intrinsic height/width of the image (and are HTML5 only).

I used an image of a beautiful butterfly, from a file with height 300 and width 400. And this Javascript:

```
var img = document.getElementById("img1");

console.log(img.height,           img.width);
console.log(img.naturalHeight,    img.naturalWidth);
console.log($("#img1").height(),  $("#img1").width());
```

**Then I used this HTML, with inline CSS for the height and width.**

```
<img style="height:120px;width:150px;" id="img1" src="img/Butterfly.jpg" />
```

Results:

```
/*Image Element*/ height == 300         width == 400
       naturalHeight == 300  naturalWidth == 400
/*Jquery*/      height() == 120       width() == 150

/*Actual Rendered size*/    120                  150
```

**I then changed the HTML to the following:**

```
<img height="90" width="115" id="img1" src="img/Butterfly.jpg" />
```

i.e. using height and width attributes rather than inline styles

Results:

```
/*Image Element*/ height ==  90         width == 115
       naturalHeight == 300  naturalWidth == 400
/*Jquery*/      height() ==  90       width() == 115

/*Actual Rendered size*/     90                  115
```

**I then changed the HTML to the following:**

```
<img height="90" width="115" style="height:120px;width:150px;" id="img1" src="img/Butterfly.jpg" />
i.e. using both attributes and CSS, to see which takes precedence.
```

Results:

```
/*Image Element*/ height ==  90         width == 115
       naturalHeight == 300  naturalWidth == 400
/*Jquery*/      height() == 120       width() == 150

/*Actual Rendered size*/    120                  150
```

NOTE : I have copied this answer from [Height and Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript). Its really worth to know these differences.

Hope this helps you.